# AWS IoT Sitewise Data Access Externally

Tags: amazon-web-services, iot, aws-iot, aws-iot-greengrass, aws-iot-sitewise

I am building an initial design for my project and had a few question regarding the data storage in IoT Sitewise. I work for a manufacturing company and we are planning to use IoT Sitewise to collect the time stream data using OPCUA.

Upon reading doc, I know we will be able to create the data models and dashboards to view the data as required but I am planning to create my own react dashboard and I want to read the data in Sitewise via API gateway. So, I am stuck where I do not know how does Sitewise actually store the data and will I be able to have my lambdas crawl through the Sitewise Db's and get required information for the API calls? Is there something else I am missing or I am not aware of?

Answer (score 0):

I have few question before I answer the scenario:

1. Is there a specific reason to go with Sitewise? for e.g. using transformations and functions?
2. Do you already have an MES or Ignition system available?

If you want to use sitewise with OPC UA you will use a Sitewise connector that will transfer data to AWS IoT sitewise and the you can use AWS IOT core with rule engine, SQS or other option to store the data in Dynamo or any other DB of your choice.

If you already have a gateway system available (Ignition/Kewpare), I would recommend connecting it to the IoT core and do the data processing which is cheaper and easier.

Comment: ask your question in comments section.